# Safe to insert date directly into MySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql, date, validation

I have a form with an element of type `date`. Normally I'd run checks on things like `text` form elements, but for a `date` object - is it safe to just insert directly into the database like this? Are there any potential abuses I should be checking for before inserting security wise?

Comment: That one counted as string I think

Answer (score 3):

> So currently I have a form with an element of type date

Any form of client side checking cannot be depended upon. The browser might not support that input type or the user might bypass it.

> Are there any potential abuses I should be checking for before inserting security wise?

You're using bound parameters, so SQL injection is not a concern.

The worst that could happen is someone sends something that is not a date (or not a properly formatted data). This will have one of two outcomes:

- It doesn't meet the data syntax required by the columns data type in the table and the INSERT fails (silently since you don't test for errors)
- It gets inserted into the table (e.g. if you have a VARCHAR field) and you later try treating it as a date and get errors or bad data then.

Answer (score -1):

You should do the same sanity checks as you would for any other field.

Your **form** may only allow date entries, but I could send a POST request to your server with anything I wanted in the "date_posted" POST field, and use it for SQL injection.

Comment: May be you mean xss attack?